# How to contribute as systematic beta tester

Tags: development

I am torturing Blender 2.80 beta as video editor to try to uncover bugs. I would like to know if there is any kind of list of tests to be done, in order to help developers.

Comment: I am not familiar with any test sets for Blender, only render scenes to test, but you can post any issues to developer.blender.org. You can get in touch via mailing list or IRC too. I think also if you'd like to contribute and maintain and develop these tests you could arrange that with devs if no such tests are publicly available yet. I feel with video editing the performance is the main issue, your idea is good, it would be nice to track how performance improves with changes and maybe compare with other packages on same projects that are in public domain.